# How do we get req.path when there is no path key in req object?

Tags: node.js, express

I printed the req object and then req.path.

While i got a value in req.path, there is no path key in the req object.

I did this inside the middleware function of expressjs.

Please explain

Answer (score 0):

Most probably because, it is in prototype of req object.

Execute below snippet and check, browser console (not output of SO)

```js
var baseObj = {
  path: '/abc'
}

var newObj = Object.create(baseObj);

console.log(newObj);
console.log(newObj.path);
```

Comment: this makes sense on the browser but req is an express object so i need to console.log on node. there i do not see _proto too

Comment: Because, Node.js console doesn't display it. You can retrieve prototype using `Object.getPrototypeOf()` and console it.

Comment: Use following line `console.log(Object.keys(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(req))))`